# Turn Off Bell Notification when comment is added on Post

Tags: apex, lightning, case, notification

I have created a post on case object record. When any user adds comment to that post, I receive a bell notification like below
[image]

I have checked if there are any automated process that is firing this but could not find anything. I have also checked support setting but there is no setting that is firing this.

So, is there a way I can turn off this bell notification?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, it is possible to turn off the notification from this screen

[image]

Click your avatar at the top of the page, and select Settings. Enter Chatter in the Quick Find box, then select Chatter Email Settings or Email Notifications—whichever one appears.
From any group page, click Email Me... | Email Settings.

See [Guidelines for Managing Your Personal Chatter Email Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_email_notify.htm&type=5)for list of all available settings around comments on posts

Comment: But this is for Email Notifications. I need to turn off bell notification for Feed Comment.

Comment: Does this turn off bell notifications for Feed Comment? Go to Setup | Select Salesforce notification | Uncheck Enable in-app Notification and Enable push notification to prevent any notification when using Salesforce.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1appadmin.meta/salesforce1appadmin/s1_admin_guide_notifications.htm

Comment: This does in fact disable notifications but it does it for entire org and also for both standard and custom notifications. So, it might not be feasible to disable it since we might need this for other object but yes, unchecking this will stop bell notifications.